# What is the result of KEY 10th MEMORIAL Popularity poll?

Tags: key

What is the result of KEY 10th MEMORIAL Popularity poll (KEY 10th MEMORIAL 人気投票)? An official source is expected.

Comment: What popularity would this poll be measuring...? I'm not sure I've heard of it before, or if it's really done by the actual *Key* folks (the ones behind other Anime).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## There are 4 popularity polls

1. Famous quotes
2. "Infamous" quotes (famous due to its wackiness)
3. Favorite products
4. Favorite characters

Source: [Ameba Blog (Japanese)](https://ameblo.jp/kakushidama/entry-10313968871.html)

---

### Famous Quotes

1. 2522 「…もうゴール、してもいいよね」(*...mou Goal, shitemo iiyo ne*)
2. 1926 「…この町と、住人に幸あれ」 (*...kono machi to, jyuunin ni kou are*)
3. 1677 「起きないから、奇跡って言うんですよ」 (*okinai kara, kiseki-tte iu-n desuyo*)
4. 1105 「俺のほうが、ずっとずっとおまえたちのことが好きなんだよ！！」 (*ore no hou ga, zutto zutto omae-tachi no koto ga suki nandayo!!*)
5. 988 「ゴールっ…」 (*Goal...*)
6. 949 「…ボクのこと、忘れてください…」 (*...boku no koto, wasurete kudasai...*)
7. 819 「さあ、いこう　世界は美しく　そして　人生はかくも素晴らしい It's a Wonderful Life!」 (*saa, ikou  sekai wa utsukushii  soshite  jinsei wa kaku mo subarasashii  It's a Wonderful Life!*)
8. 650 「夢を叶えろ、渚ああぁーーーーーーーーっ！　子の夢が親の夢なんだよっ！」 (*yume wo kanaero, nagisaaa----! ko no yume ga oya no yume nandayo!*)
9. 624 「ふざけるな…　茶番だあぁぁぁーーーーーーーーーっ！！　恭介ぇぇーーー！！」 (*fuzakeruna... chaban daaa----!! Kyousukee---!!*)
10. 585 「もし、よろしければ…　あなたを…　あなたを、お連れしましょうか　この町の願いが叶う場所に」 (*moshi, yoroshikereba... anata wo... anata wo, otsureshimashouka kono machi no negai ga kanau basho ni*)
11. 「…さなえさんが、ないていいのは……おトイレか…パパのむねだって…」 (*...sanae-san ga, naite ii no wa... otoire ka... papa no mune datte...*)
12. 「…飛べない翼に意味はあるんでしょうか」 (*...tobenai tsubasa ni imi wa aru-n deshouka*)
13. 「コールドゲームだ」 (*Cold Game da*)
14. 「春がきて…ずっと春だったらいいのに」 (*haru ga kite... zutto haru dattara ii noni*)
15. 「チーム名は…リトルバスターズだ」 (*Team na wa... Little Busters da*)
16. 「リトルバスターズは不滅だ…」 (*Little Busters wa fumetsu da...*)
17. 「この学校は、好きですか」 (*kono gakkou wa, suki desuka*)
18. 「人生の宝物を探しにいこう―――」 (*jinsei no takaramono wo sagashi ni ikou*)
19. 「永遠に続いていく愛はある、絶対に」 (*eien ni tsuzuite iku ai wa aru, zettai ni*)
20. 「はい、町も人も、みんな家族です　だんご大家族です」 (*hai, machi mo hito mo, minna kazoku desu dango daikazoku desu*)

---

#### Infamous Quotes

1. 2834 「それと便座カバー」 (*sore to benza cover*)
2. 1594 「うぐぅ」 (*ugu*)
3. 1248 「筋肉筋肉ー！！」 (*kinniku kinniku-!!*)
4. 1040 「いやっほーぅ！　国崎最高ー！」 (*iyahho-u! kuzaki saikou-!*)
5. 637 「んまっ　つぁ　ちょぎ！」 (*n-ma tsu-a chogi!*)

---

### Favorite Products

1. 17147 CLANNAD
2. 11739 Little Busters!: EX
3. 4797 AIR
4. 4069 Little Busters!
5. 2743 Kanon

---

### Favorite Characters

1. 4160 Tomoyo Sakagami (CLANNAD)
2. 3822 Nagisa Furukawa (CLANNAD)
3. 3315 Saya Tokido (Little Busters!: EX)
4. 2938 Misuzu Kamio (AIR)
5. 2782 Kyou Fujibayashi (CLANNAD)
6. 2652 Kudryavka Noumi (Little Busters!)
7. 2392 Kyousuke Natsume (Little Busters!)
8. 1833 Fuko Ibuki (CLANNAD)
9. 1703 Rin Natsume (Little Busters!)
10. 1534 Kanata Futaki (Little Busters!)

---

There's no *full online* official source, but it's listed in the "KEY 10th MEMORIAL BOX OFFICIAL BOOK" inside of [Key 10th Memorial BOX](http://key.visualarts.gr.jp/10thfes/memorialbox.htm).

[image: character popularity ranking]

<sub>[Image source](http://hit4.blog4.fc2.com/blog-entry-288.html)</sub>

However, Jun Maeda explicitly stated that Saya Tokido won the third place in the popularity poll and gave hints to the top 2 in the [official KEY blog (Japanese)](http://key.visualarts.gr.jp/angelbeats/blog/2009/06/post_4.html).

<sup>[Thanks to Gao's comment](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/41993/what-is-the-result-of-key-10th-memorial-popularity-poll/41994#comment56678_41994)</sup>